# Getting a 404 on defined urls in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to access urls defined in django app (`abcd`).

apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'rest_framework',
    "abcd",
]
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls), path('', include('abcd.urls'))
]
```

`abcd.urls`

```
from rest_framework import routers

from abcd import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet, 'users')
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet, 'groups')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

`views.py`

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet


class UserViewSet(ViewSet):
    pass


class GroupViewSet(ViewSet):
    pass
```

Whenever I try accessing: http://localhost:8000/users or http://localhost:8000/groups, I get a 404.

**Edit**

For some obscure reason, whenever I do the below, the urls are resolved:

```
class UserViewSet(ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        pass

class GroupViewSet(ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        pass
```

Comment: If you set `DEBUG = True` in settings.py, it will show a list of the urls that it tried.  That might provide some useful info.

Comment: ```[07/Mar/2024 04:23:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10052
Not Found: /users
[07/Mar/2024 04:23:30] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 404 2452
Not Found: /groups
[07/Mar/2024 04:23:34] "GET /groups HTTP/1.1" 404 2455```

Comment: Is the file literally named `abcd.urls` ??

Comment: `abcd` is the name of the app which contains a file named `urls.py`

Comment: Then your question is confusing, because that's the name you gave for that file.  Maybe you should edit your question to show `abcd/urls.py` as the name.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `include('abcd.urls')` instead of using a regular import on that module?

Comment: it doesn't make a difference if I make it `include(abcd.urls)` instead, I still get the same outcome.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of setting `DEBUG = True`, to see the list of known urls reported on the 404 error page?

Comment: yes, check above, i included what is logged

Comment: I'm not talking about the webserver error log.  I'm talking about the actual 404 page that is displayed in the browser.  If you have `DEBUG = True`, the page will show a bunch of possibly useful information.

Comment: ```admin/
^$ [name='api-root']
^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']```

Comment: Also, in the code you posted, `include(abcd.urls)` would be an error because `abcd` is not defined.

Comment: i imported it at my end to try your suggestion and it didn't work

Comment: One upvote from me. This is a really good question which kept me awake since 3AM.

Comment: lol, it kept me awake for hours yesterday as well, then I woke up and wasted a few more hours until the issue was resolved. Now I'm trying to figure out how to convert all views to `APIView`s instead of `ViewSet`s, but it keeps complaining that a view doesn't have a `get_extra_actions`, looks like there will be more wasted hours on this one as well, thanks to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultRouter` generates routes for a `ViewSet` according to the available methods on the `ViewSet`.  A `ViewSet` class does not provide any method handlers such as `.get()` or `.post()`, but instead provides actions such as `.list()` and `.create()`. [See the full mapping here. <sup>[django-rest-framework.org]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions)

Since your `ViewSet` does not have any methods, a get request will return a 404 status code with status text *—Not Found*.

Comment: Only `create()` and `list()` work. The same outcome is obtained even if `post()` and `get()` are defined.

Comment: The `ViewSet` doesn’t use `.get()` and `.post()` like other class based views but uses methods such as `.list()` and `.create()`, `.partial_update()` and `.destroy()`. It is these methods that you must override.